# django - Creating custom queryset for RelatedManager

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I tried about 25 Stackoverflow links and nobody seems to have a working solution for this problem.

I created a custom queryset like this:

```
class ProjectQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
   def get_active(self):
       from apps.projectmanagement.models import Project
       return self.filter(active=True)

class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
      return ProjectQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

This works great if I start at the model like

```
Project.objects.get_active()
```

But if I want to use it in a relation, no luck so far:

```
employee.projects.get_active()
```

I always get this error:

> AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_active'

What I've tried so far:

1. I read that `use_for_related_fields = True` in the manager class is deprecated. Does not work anyway on django v2.1
2. Adding this in my model, as half the internet states:

   class Project(models.Model):
   ...
   objects = ProjectManager()

   ```
   class Meta:
       base_manager_name = 'objects'
   ```
3. Trying to avoid the `RelatedManager` and to work with a queryset:

   employee.projects.all().get_active()

Any ideas what I've been doing wrong? And how would I solve this? Can't be too hard, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access), "Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models". The example they give is for going in the other direction, ie `project.employee`.

There is no way to do this using managers themselves. The best bet is to define a method on your model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_active_projects(self):
        return self.projects.filter(active=True)
        # or
        return Project.objects.filter(employee=self).get_active()
```